# Kendo.Culture('de-DE') multiplies Grid value by 100

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

Working on changing culture in the application through Kendo.culture('de-DE'), the default set is en-US. However, doing simple culture change is messing with the values when the culture is 'de-DE', it is multiplying the grid values by 100.

[image: With de-DE]

[image: With en-US (correct Value)]

Does anyone know what could be the reason behind the values being multiplied by 100. I am using this source code

```
<script defer src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out regarding this issue, If your grid values are getting multiplied by 100 mostly in the case when you use kendo.culture('de-DE');

It is possible that you are applying de-DE on number which are string format. So change those number which are in string and make it number data type. Then it works as expected